# RTF to PDF Convertor on CentOS Server

Tags: pdf, conversion, centos, rtf

I am trying to find a free program for a CentOS server to convert RTF files to PDF.

I installed `unrtf`, but it doesn't seem to convert to PDFs. I'm looking for something that is terminal based, no GUI.

Answer (score 1):

I found a shell script that claims to convert RTF files to PDFs.

#### [rtf2pdf.sh](http://old.zope.org/Members/guylux/rtf2pdf.sh/file_view)

Dependencies:

- [Ted](http://www.nllgg.nl/Ted/) ("an easy rich text processor")
- [Ghostscript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/) (guide for CentOS 5.4 [here](http://chrisschuld.com/2010/01/updating-ghostscript-on-centos-5-4-ghostscript-8-70/))

Here's also a Stack Overflow question: [Is there a free way to convert RTF to PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586411/is-there-a-free-way-to-convert-rtf-to-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [PyODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/pyodconverter)

> PyODConverter, for Python OpenDocument Converter, is a Python script that automates office document conversions from the command line using OpenOffice.org.
>
> The script does basically the same thing as the command line tool that comes with JODConverter but is much simpler. In fact the Python script was released for the people who use JODConverter only from the command line (not as a Java library or web service) and would like a simpler alternative.